# main tag completely ignores third child element of the <div class="options">

Tags: html, css

```js
var bannerStatus = 1;
var bannerTimer = 3000;

window.onload = function() {
  bannerLoop();
}

var startBannerLoop = setInterval(function() {
  bannerLoop();
}, bannerTimer);

document.getElementById("main-banner").onmouseenter = function() {
  clearInterval(startBannerLoop);
}

document.getElementById("main-banner").onmouseleave = function() {
  startBannerLoop = setInterval(function() {
    bannerLoop();
  }, bannerTimer);
}

document.getElementById("imgbanbtn-prev").onclick = function() {
  if (bannerStatus === 1) {
    bannerStatus = 2;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 2) {
    bannerStatus = 3;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 3) {
    bannerStatus = 1;
  }
  bannerLoop();
};

document.getElementById("imgbanbtn-next").onclick = function() {
  bannerLoop();
};

function bannerLoop() {
  if (bannerStatus === 1) {
    document.getElementById("img-ban2").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("img-ban1").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("img-ban1").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("img-ban2").style.right = "-1200px";
      document.getElementById("img-ban2").style.zIndex = "1500";
      document.getElementById("img-ban3").style.right = "1200px";
      document.getElementById("img-ban3").style.zIndex = "500";
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("img-ban2").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus = 2;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 2) {
    document.getElementById("img-ban3").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("img-ban2").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("img-ban2").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("img-ban3").style.right = "-1200px";
      document.getElementById("img-ban3").style.zIndex = "1500";
      document.getElementById("img-ban1").style.right = "1200px";
      document.getElementById("img-ban1").style.zIndex = "500";
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("img-ban3").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus = 3;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 3) {
    document.getElementById("img-ban1").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("img-ban3").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("img-ban3").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("img-ban1").style.right = "-1200px";
      document.getElementById("img-ban1").style.zIndex = "1500";
      document.getElementById("img-ban2").style.right = "1200px";
      document.getElementById("img-ban2").style.zIndex = "500";
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("img-ban1").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus = 1;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
}

header {
  background-color: white;
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px darkgrey;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999999;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  padding: calc(1rem / 1.618);
}

.logo {
  flex: 1 1 70%;
  max-width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo img {
  width: 20%;
}

nav .btn {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1.1% 1.2%;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0 none;
}

nav .open {
  display: block !important;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

nav .navbar-collapse {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav,
nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item {}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link,
nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item .dropdown-link {
  padding: calc(1em / 1.618);
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: red;
}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item .dropdown-link {
  color: black;
}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item .dropdown-link:hover {
  background-color: #AAAA;
  color: white;
}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown {}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.dropdown-toggle {}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.dropdown-toggle:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {}

main {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: .8%;
  margin-right: .8%;
}

.main-banner {
  margin: 2% auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-banner .img-ban {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.main-banner #img-ban3 {
  background-image: url("3d-grids.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.main-banner #img-ban2 {
  background-image: url("black.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.main-banner #img-ban1 {
  background-image: url("starWars.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.imgban-btn {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 6%;
  height: 24px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 2000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.imgban-btn:hover {
  opacity: .9;
}

.imgbanbtn-prev {
  left: 1%;
  background-image: url("back-arrow.png");
  background-size: 60%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.imgbanbtn-next {
  right: 1%;
  background-image: url("next-arrow.png");
  background-size: 60%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.imgban-box {}

.main-banner .imgban-box h2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-banner .imgban-box p {
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-banner #img-ban3 .imgban-box {
  padding-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-banner #img-ban2 .imgban-box {
  padding-top: 15%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.main-banner #img-ban1 .imgban-box {
  padding-top: 15%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  margin-left: 7%;
  float: left;
}

main .options {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.3%;
}

main .options .service {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: #f5f6fa;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5% auto;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 2%;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px black;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  margin-top: 10%;
  padding: 1.3% 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 1% 1%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 520px) {
  .main-banner {
    height: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1350px) {
  .main-banner {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1530px) {
  .main-banner {
    width: 1200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cb3417b510.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="M-TECH">
      </a>
      <button class="btn" type="button" data-target="#navigation">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Dropdown menu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Dropdown item 1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Dropdown item 2</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Dropdown item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 4</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="main-banner" id="main-banner">
      <div class="imgban-btn imgbanbtn-prev" id="imgbanbtn-prev"></div>
      <div class="img-ban" id="img-ban3">
        <div class="imgban-box">
          <h2>3D Grids</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="img-ban" id="img-ban2">
        <div class="imgban-box">
          <h2>Black</h2>
          <p>Darkness Awaits</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="img-ban" id="img-ban1">
        <div class="imgban-box">
          <h2>Star Wars</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="imgban-btn imgbanbtn-next" id="imgbanbtn-next"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="service">
        <h2>Tire alignment</h2>
        <p>$30.99</p>
      </div>
      <div class="service">
        <h2>Oil change</h2>
        <p>$12.99</p>
      </div>
      <div class="service">
        <h2>Car wash</h2>
        <p>$5.99 - basic</p>
        <p>$8.99 - premium</p>
        <p>$12.99 - gold</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>Alladin Assaf</li> |
      <li>UTA</li> |
      <li>For grading purposes only</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

My footer is overlapping my third child element of my div class="options" tag. It seems that my main tag completely ignores the third child element of that div element. The problem did not start until I added CSS, but I don't know which property it is. I have been trying to figure what the problem is but I cannot seem to figure it out. Can someone help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add a minimal reproduceable example to your question.

Comment: Impossible to answer with the data provided.

Comment: Can you add the code that will let us reproduce the problem ourselves? Without seeing the html and css relevant to the problem we're probably not going to be able to help.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve]